# What is the best to do linux administration via web interfae

Tags: linux, web

I have written few shell scripts which can do specific tasks .

But my mangaer wants that there should be some web interface where , he can run those scripts and function using web .

Now i don't know how can i link bash with web .

I know PHP.

Also one thing more if i use python can i make web interface , or will it easir than programming in bash

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your manager insists there are some solutions like [webmin](http://www.webmin.com) or [zentyal](http://www.zentyal.com) to manage GNU/linux servers from a web interface.

You can easily add your own scripts to those web interfaces. The advantage of using tested products over your own reinvent-the-wheel web service is that those web services are developed with security in mind.

**However** as a sysadmin I encourage you to admin your servers using just a shell (bash with screen for example) through ssh.

Comment: cpanel is also doing the same thing . Can i make small GUI in Bash that can do the stuff . can i see the same gui in putty client

Comment: No, you cant have a single GUI that can be displayed in a terminal and in a web browser.

Answer (score 3):

I would highly **NOT** recommend to write a software in PHP, that has access to /bin or other relevant system parts and serve it via apache. Because: PHP is not strict, reliable and secure enough to realize programs as Webmin with.

But I wonder at all, why a manager would want to do administrative tasks on a server? Are those really administrative tasks? Or is it something, you could write in PHP from scratch? I mean, If he just wants to shrink an image, you don't need a bash script for that.

I wrote a remote installer in python once, that was only accessible in the companies intranet and executed a few scripts via an SSH connection, using certificates. It worked, but was really not a good solution. But I would recommend a way like this one, to have a relatively secure way to hack this together.

Answer (score 1):

Webmin allows you to use commands via a remote interface.

http://www.webmin.com/

Comment: but i want to create my own small interface like click here to backup , click here to restore etc

Comment: But why? Something is already made to do just what you want.

Answer (score 1):

In case you don't prefer your manager to work on Webmin, and would like to have a simple user interface where your manager can work directly,

YES, you can link PHP and BASH using [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php):

- Create your GUI directory (ex: /var/www/html/MyManagerGUI/).

  `# mkdir /var/www/html/MyManagerGUI/`
- Put your Bash scripts in one directory (ex: /var/www/MyManagerGUI/Scripts/), and give them execution permesion.

  `# chmod +x /var/www/MyManagerGUI/Scripts/*`
- Create index.php file in /var/www/MyManagerGUI/
- In your index.php file, call the Bash scripts from PHP by:

  `<?php exec("cd Scripts/;./MyBash arg1 arg2" , $output); ?>`

where `$output` is array contains all the results from your Bash, `MyBash` is your bash name, and `arg1 arg2` are optional arguments

- Change MyManagerGUI/ owner to Apahce

  `# chown -R apache:apache /var/www/MyManagerGUI/`
- To secure your GUI, you can add [.htaccess](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Htaccess) file in /var/www/MyManagerGUI/, like adding username and password or force https access.